# Error, Eval unbound variable python GIMP, I know its a simple mistake, Any help is much appreciated

Tags: command-line, python, gimp

Getting an Unbound variable while trying this script from the Windows command prompt

Works perfect from the GIMP Menu, but not from command

```
SET gimpEXE="C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.8.exe"

for %i in ("C:\Users\abeta4\Desktop\ImgTest\*.jpg") do %gimpEXE% -i -b "(python-fu-resize %i TRUE)" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"
```

Then the script
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
from gimpfu import *

def plugin_main(timg, tdrawable, savecopy=TRUE):


    newWidth = 768
    newHeight = 1080
    timgsx = "sx"      

    pdb.gimp_image_scale(timg, newWidth, newHeight)

    if savecopy:
        pdb.file_png_save2(timg, tdrawable, "C:\\Users\\abeta4\\Downloads\\%s%s.png" % (timgsx, timg.name), timg.name+".jpg", 1,9,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)

register(
    "python_fu_resize",
    "Saves the image at a maximum width and height",
    "Saves the image at a maximum width and height",
    "xxx",
    "xxx",
    "2017",
    "<Image>/Image/Resize For Screens, Now Even Easier :)...",
    "*",
    [
        (PF_BOOL, "copy", "Make a PNG copy", TRUE),

    ],
    [],
    plugin_main)

main()
```

Python beginner here, so sorry for noob mistakes in script.

Answer (score 0):

The way your plugin is defined, it takes an image, a drawable, and a parameter. But

1. when you call it, you only give an image name and a parameter
2. the python code in your `plugin_main` expects `timg` to be a `gimp.Image` object, not just a file name. So something would have to load the image first.
3. the registration code only declares the parameter, and omits the image and drawable.

In practice your python script doesn't even need to be declared as a plugin.

See [this similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892234/6378557) for some sample code and explanations and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435560/6378557) for some more explanations.